# .htaccess 301 redirect, URLs have different identifiers

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, seo

here is my problem. Lets say these pages show details about a home that is being sold.

I have an old URL like:

```
www.example.com/home-details-12345.html
```

After a website redesign, the new URL looks like:

```
www.example.com/new-york-home-56789/
```

Where `12345` and `56789` are both unique identifiers for that home. So, I'm trying to redirect an old URL that used id1 to identify the home in the database, to a new URL that uses another identifier, id2.
  Basically, the URLs have nothing in common.

**I can however retrieve id2 based on id1.** So, my question is, how can I achieve this? Bear in mind there are over 100K homes, so manual redirects are out of the question.

I guess I need to make a RewriteRule for `home-details-id1.html` to a script, like `getPage.php` , where I can retrieve `id2` using `id1`, and make a second redirect to the correct page.

But how do I do this? How will google handle this from a SEO point of view? Thank you!

Comment: I think your on the right track.How you do it is up to your programmer. If you work out the new URL in the code you just have to do a 301 redirect. A php 301 redirect is exactly what you want to do for SEO purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no SEO expert, but I guess Google (or any other search engine for that matter) will recognize HTTP 301 redirection as "Moved permanently", so will try to index old URLs instead new ones. You could do a silent redirect by pointing Your RewriteRule to php script that would include old url (ie. `include("home-details-12345.html");` ).

However, that will produce quite a lot of overhead, and You really don't want to do that. Try to change Your software's logic so it complies with Your front-end - it's really the best practice for theese kind of issues, and even though it'll cost You some time, it WILL pay off in the future.

Comment: As far as I know, doing a 301 redirect tells google, look, the content from url XXX, has moved permanently to url yyy, so index url yyy for that content.
Anyway, that does not help. The logic I'm using now is the correct one. I'm trying to do redirects for the old URLs, that used id1 as identifier (which is wrong), so I don't loose so much traffic. (which I already did, quite a lot).